# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jconnect decimal issue

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, spring-jdbc

I am using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to insert data into a table. (Spring 2.5.3/Java 1.6)
I am using jconnect driver to connect to sybase `jdbc:sybase:Tds:<Server>:<Port>`.
For some reason the decimal values the decimal part is truncated.

With the same code if I use jtds driver (`jdbc:jtds:sybase://<Servername>:<Port>`) its working fine.

I cannot use jtds as jconn is being used by other code.

In Java objects, field is defined as double. In database, field is defined as float (numeric with precision does not work).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to be Number Formating from "Regional and Language Settings".

Go to Control Panel -> "Regional and Language Settings" -> Customize and change the "Decimal Symbol". If it's a "." put a ",", or vice-versa.